# How to get a java File object given the path (in form of String or Path)?

Tags: java, file, path

So, actually made my research and it seems there's no good answer out there.
My code was tought to make a new .txt file if the file doesn't exist and to get the existing file in case that file id already created. Source comes here:

```
package ficheros_texto;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWritter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TestClass{
    private File f;
    private String path;
    public TestClass() throws IOException{
        String user=System.getProperty("user.name");
        this.path="C:\\users\\"+user+"\\documents\\pass_manager_data.txt");
        f=new File(path);
    }
    public void createFile(){
        try{
            if(!f.exists()){
                BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
                f.createNewFile();
                writer.write("USERNAME\t|\tPASSWORD");
                writer.close();
            }
            //else{ problem being here }
        }
        catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine...what exact functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Just a general advice: Instead of reading the `user.name` system property and generating the path to the user's home dir manually, you should read the `user.home` property. `String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");this.path=userHome+"\\documents\\pass_manager_data.txt";`

Comment: "Your code looks fine...what exact functionality are you looking for? "

I want to cover the `else` case. In case the file already exists, I want this method to establish the class' private attribute `f` as the file that already exists in the given path.

Comment: strip out irrelevant tags